# Не работает команда webbrowser.open

Tags: telegram, telebot, бот

Пишу своего бота в телеграмме, такая проблема что я добавил функцию, которая при определенном сообщении боту открывается сайт, но что то она не работает и ничего не открывается

```
import time
import webbrowser
import telebot


bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(command=['/vk'])
    def site(message):
        webbrowser.open('http://vk.com')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def main(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}', )


@bot.message_handler()
    def info(message):
        if message.text.lower() == 'привет':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}')
        elif message.text.lower() == 'id':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'ID: {message.from_user.id}')


 bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: "которая при определенном сообщении боту открывается сайт" какое сообщение?

Comment: сообщение /vk должно открывать, но что то да

Comment: у вас в коде сообщением в телеграмме "//vk"

Answer (score 0):

Есть 2 способа(не считая Web App), которые предлагает телеграм, чтобы открыть ссылку.

```
def inline_markup():
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("VK", url="https://vk.com"))
    return markup


@bot.message_handler(commands=['vk'])
def open_website(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     "Выбери либо на клавиатуре, либо в <a href='https://vk.com/'>сообщении</a>",
                     parse_mode='html', reply_markup=inline_markup())
```

И у вас опять ошибка в коде, после декоратора не нужна табуляция.

Comment: мне нужно именно что бы после того как отправить боту /vk, открывался сайт с вк

Comment: Я вас понял, но кроме как локально(у вас) он нигде не откроется(у пользователя)

Comment: а как сделать так, что бы сайт открывался у поьзователя?

Comment: К сожалению, на сколько я знаю, никак, можно только через мои способы. Если бы кто-то знал, я думаю уже бы написали